# Postgres,functions,before insert vladate arrays values

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my function `

```
create or replace function test.insert(_orderid integer, __partnerids      
integer[], __maginitude double precision[])
returns boolean
language plpgsql
as $$
DECLARE  res boolean;
BEGIN
PERFORM orderid
FROM test.order_partner_magnitude
WHERE orderid = _orderid
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;

DELETE
FROM test.order_partner_magnitude
WHERE orderid = _orderId;

INSERT INTO test.order_partner_magnitude(orderid, partnerid, magnitude)
SELECT _orderId, unnest(__partnerids),unnest(__maginitude);

res =true ;
RETURN res;
end ;
$$;
```

Some using example `SELECT test.insert(1, '{30,10,20}','{46,59,12}');` result will be

```
orderid | partnerid | magnitude
      1 |        30 |        46
      1 |        10 |        59
      1 |        20 |        12
```

now I need to check is parter busy,I can get busy partners id with this query 
`SELECT partnerid from test.order_partner WHERE status = 1`;

Example partner with id 20 is busy after insert result must be `

```
orderid | partnerid | magnitude
      1 |        30 |        46
      1 |        10 |        59
```

I want to insert all data with 1 insert query like in function so cant loop  over `partnerid` from arguments,are there any other way to do it?If there are no way to do it,I can change data types,example `[[partnerid, magnitude],[partnerid, magnitude]......]` or any other type witch will help solve this.

Answer (score 1):

doable in one query, EG:

```
db=# with c(o, p, m) as (values (1, '{30,10,20}'::int[],'{46,59,12}'::int[]))
, op(i, status) as (values(20,1))
, mypart as (select o, unnest(p) pa, unnest(m) me from c)
select mypart.*
from mypart
left outer join op on i = pa
where i is null;
 o | pa | me
---+----+----
 1 | 30 | 46
 1 | 10 | 59
(2 rows)
```

so for you smth like:

```
INSERT INTO test.order_partner_magnitude(orderid, partnerid, magnitude)
with c(o, p, m) as (values (_orderId, __partnerids, __maginitude))
    , mypart as (select o, unnest(p) pa, unnest(m) me from c)
    select mypart.*
    from mypart
    left outer join test.order_partner on partner_id = pa
    where i is null;
```

Comment: in may case there is no need of this `c(o, p, m) as (values (_orderId, __partnerids, __maginitude))` as I use this in function. I think `unnest` returns every value as row `orderid, partnerid,magnitude`,is it write?And partners with `status =1` must be ignored,witch is better `where partnerid is null and status<>1` or `left outer join test.order_partner on partnerid = pa and status=1`?

Comment: yes, I used cte just to demostrate its working... which is better depends on amount of data and structure... you may try asking it in SO